# Need help trying to create a simple script

Tags: autohotkey

So I have no idea what I'm really doing, but I need help with a very simple script.

The basic idea is to press a key, such as k, four times each second, repeating until the script is turned off with a command (Alt-x).

I'm using Autohotkey script editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Timers](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).

Example code:

```
F1::                          ;key that launches this code
    SetTimer, SendKeyK,250    ;set timer to repeat every 250 miliseconds
return                        ;end

F2::
    SetTimer, SendKeyK,Off    ;turn of the timer
return


SendKeyK:
    Send, {k}    ;timer sends (presses) the key k
return
```

As you can see there is no need to exit the script.